# Import XML in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spotify

I am trying to import the amount of followers from a Spotify artist. The only problem is it's inside a react modular. I used to be able to get the full xpath from dev tools, however, I believe the react modular is causing any error.

Any ideas on how I could get around this to use import xml to get the amount of spotify followers?
Example link: https://open.spotify.com/artist/1Xyo4u8uXC1ZmMpatF05PJ?si=VGW1om-XTNew5VD-KQ-7xA

Thanks!

Comment: Where's the XML? This just links to an artist page

Comment: About `I am trying to import the amount of followers from a Spotify artist.`, in your provided URL, where can I see your expected value?

Comment: @camille There is no import xml because that's what the question is on lol.

Comment: @Tanaike IF you scroll to the bottom and click the image under about you will see followers.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't find your expected number in the HTML. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I think that I have to study more.

Comment: @Tanaike Right now it's only available in the desktop app or web player. Go to artist page and scroll down and click on about section. You'll get a popup with the followers count.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Ah, is that in developer tools? Im not too sure where I can find obj. Thank you`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @camille /html/body/div[17]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1] this is the XPATH. Does that help?

Comment: No, not without knowing at least what element you're trying to get. Browser extensions change the HTML on a page, so AFAIK the 17th div for me isn't necessarily the 17th div for you. It's still unclear *how* you're trying to do anything here

Comment: @camille I see sorry for the confusion. Let me try to reexplain... I am trying to import the number of followers an artist has on Spotify to a cell in google sheets. I usually use importXML to import data from the web, however the data is in a react modular which makes it hard to extract and I'm confused. Hopefully that helps.